# Phases of cardiac cycle

Tags: cardiology, homework

what is the correct sequence for cardiac cycle

Sequence 1: a. Atrial systole b. Ventricular systole c. Combined diastole

Sequence2 a. Atrial systole/Ventricular diastole b. Ventricular systole/atrial diastole c.Atrial systole/Ventricular diastole

In internet I found sequence 1 but however in my book sequence 2 is followed. So can anyone clear my doubt?

Comment: They're actually the same except that sequence 2 includes the beginning of the next heart beat as step C. It's just two ways of writing the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

They read very similarly to each other but I am sure they are viewing the cardiac cycle from different points.

2 is to explain atrium and ventricle are contracting alternatively(they are not in systole at the same time).
1 is to explain there are three distinct periods in the cardiac cycle: atrial systole, ventricular systole, both diastole.